# Hash#stringify_keys undefined

Tags: ruby

When I run `ri Hash`, the `stringify_keys` method shows up as an instance method in some of the listings where, each listing appears to be associated with a different gem or gem version.

But when I try calling it from the irb shell, it fails:

```
irb(main):035:0> h
=> {:this=>"this value", :that=>"that value"}
irb(main):031:0> h.instance_of? Hash
=> true
irb(main):032:0> h.stringify_keys
NoMethodError: undefined method `stringify_keys' for {:this=>"this value", :that=>"that value"}:Hash
        from (irb):32
        from /usr/local/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Also, when I run `h.methods.sort` in IRB, `stringify_keys` isn't listed as a method.

Can someone explain this discrepancy?  Is it a matter of my environment being outdated or just something I don't understand about the Ruby documentation?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rails (via ActiveSupport) monkey patches the [`stringify_keys`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-stringify_keys) method into [`Hash`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Hash.html) so you won't have it in a plain `irb` session. You can load the core extensions by saying:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext'
```

See the [Active Support Core Extensions Guide](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_support_core_extensions.html) for details on loading individual monkey patches.

Comment: Does Rails add it into the `ri` documentation for Hash too?

Comment: @MarkThomas: I don't know, someone might be. I never use `ri`, I always use the online documentation or read the source code to figure things out.